# How to display pdf file format based on each id in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to display files in pdf format stored in the public folder, but it hasn't worked. please help how to display files with pdf format based on each id on laravel 8. Here is the script I'm trying to make. thank you.

Route:

```
Route::get('suratmsk/preview-pdf/{id}', [Srtmsk1Controller::class, 'viewPDF'])->name('viewPDF');
```

Controller:

```
public function viewPDF($id){
   $file = storage_path('app/dokumen/') . $id . '.pdf';
   if (file_exists($file))
   {
      $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'];
      return response()->download($file, 'Test File', $headers, 'inline');
   } else {
      abort(404, 'File not found!');
   }
}
```

View:

```
<iframe src="{{url('suratmsk/viewPDF')}}/{{$suratmsk->dokumen}}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"> </iframe>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing the PDF path in the database, and you want to access the file publicly, you can access it directly in the iFrame without having to render it using `response()->download();` you can use response download if you want to download the file, but to render it in iFrame you need to only pass the file path.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

> The public disk included in your application's filesystems
> configuration file is intended for files that are going to be publicly
> accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and
> stores its files in storage/app/public.
>
> To make these files accessible from the web, you should create a
> symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public. Utilizing
> this folder convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one
> directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero
> down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.
>
> To create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan
> command:

**Step 1)** link the public path to storage path

```
php artisan storage:link
```

**Step 2)** return the view containing the model you are accessing:

```
public function viewPDF(Suratmsk $suratmsk){
   return view('yourView', compact('suratmsk'));
}
```

**Step 3)** access the file directly in view using iFrame, there are many helpers to accomplish accessing the url https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#urls-method-list but in this case, I used asset()

```
<iframe src="{{ asset('storage/dokumen/'.$suratmsk->dokumen) }}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"> </iframe>
```

Good luck!